# Count tokens across different raws in a column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

how to count total number of "**tokens**" in a column after using `nltk.word_tokenizer`

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

train['doc_text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

I have tried counting the values but it does not work, I guess because I am dealing with strings.

There are over 18K rows, and as expected after doing `word_tokenize` there are separated words in each row.

I would like to know the total number of 'tokens' I have in the column.

Comment: You want to find unique tokens or total number of tokens?

Comment: Good point, thank you. Total number of tokens.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar thank you, it works

Comment: @AkshayNEvrekar I guess the following code would give me the unique values df['count'].unique , can you confirm? thanks

Comment: Nope!! It will only give you unique counts(int values)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar thank you very much for your time and help. All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
# create a new column to get count of tokens
df['count'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(word_tokenize(x)))

# do summation on a column
total_tokens = df['count'].sum()
print(total_tokens)
```